# recursive function in go language

Tags: go

I started to learn go language days ago. When I tried to start writing some fun codes, I am stuck by a strange behavior.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func recv(value int) {
    if value < 0 {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(value)
    go recv(value-1)
}

func main() {
    recv(10)
}
```

when I run the above code, only `10` is printed. When I remove the `go` before the call to `recv`, `10` to `0` are printed out. I believe I am misusing go routine here, but I can not understand why it failed start a go routine this way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the main function returns, Go will not wait for any still existing goroutines to finish but instead just exit.

`recv` will return to main after the first "iteration" and because main has nothing more to do, the program will terminate.

One solution to this problem is to have a channel that signals that all work is done, like the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func recv(value int, ch chan bool) {
    if value < 0 {
        ch <- true
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(value)
    go recv(value - 1, ch)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    recv(10, ch)

    <-ch
}
```

Here, `recv` will send a single boolean before returning, and `main` will wait for that message on the channel.

For the logic of the program, it does not matter what type or specific value you use. `bool` and `true` are just a straightforward example. If you want to be more efficient, using a `chan struct{}` instead of a `chan bool` will save you an additional byte, since empty structs do not use any memory.

Comment: For signal channels, where the type of the channel data is not important, you can use `chan struct{}`. An empty struct takes up no memory, while still allowing the desired behaviour. Whereas a boolean takes up one byte.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I went for a bool to not make it any more complex. But yeah, an empty struct is technically better. Do you want to incorporate that in my answer or shall I edit it myself? :)

Comment: It's your answer, go for it :)

Answer (score 10):

A `sync.Waitgroup` is another solution and specifically intended for the purpose of waiting for an arbitrary amount of goroutines to run their course.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func recv(value int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    if value < 0 {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(value)

    wg.Add(1) // Add 1 goroutine to the waitgroup.

    go func() {
        recv(value-1, wg)
        wg.Done() // This goroutine is finished.
    }()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    recv(10, &wg)

    // Block until the waitgroup signals
    // all goroutines to be finished.
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I did so and also worked. How come?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func recv(value int) {
    if value < 0 {
      return
    }

    fmt.Println(value)
    recv(value - 1)
}

func main() {
  recv(10)
}
```

Comment: Did your second version print 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ?  Try 100 times :D

Comment: @vrbilgi It did not work. I was mistaken. Thank U. Edited. ;)